# Using sshpass in Cygwin, ssh stills prompts for password

Tags: bash, ssh, authentication, cygwin, sshpass

According to this [RedHat SSH password automation guide](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ssh-automation-sshpass) I'm following the **Example 4: GPG** one, and following the steps in that guide I create my `pass_file` using my own passphrase. Then, I got this:

```
gpg -d -q myappserver23.sshpasswd.gpg > pass_file && sshpass -fpass_file ssh myuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Note the lack of a space between the `-f` option and `pass_file` according to [sshpass man page](http://manpages.org/sshpass)
When I run the command above, I'm asked for my passphrase, I type it correctly and then I'm asked for the server's password as if `sshpass` wasn't even used.
In short, this works *but* I still got a password prompt...

I'm aware of the `-q` options certainly and I've added also `-vvv` to both *sshpass* and *ssh* and it seems this is related to *shh* and not to *sshpass* I believe.
I'll just share here the debug messages I got after the ssh banner message

```
(...)
debug3: input_userauth_banner
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Here goes ssh banner message
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:7PAz6lsENYkfYGwFZWNf0OJ88Z9mFDMSBc+P9t+4H1k
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\myuser/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
myuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx's password:
```

The last line of this output is the password prompt. Obviously, if I type my password here, I'll be able to login to the remote server but then, what's the point to use `sshpass` ? I'd like to be able to just login without having to type any password.

Please, don't advise the use of private keys, I know about the subject but its not applicable to my real world scenario.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: use keys, not passwords. any other answer is a wrong answer, just as a question refusing to consider using keys with ssh is a wrong question.    keys are **always** appropriate to real world scenarios involving ssh.

Comment: @cas Thanks but as I was saying, I know. Please consider helping answer the question as it was raised.

Comment: IMO this is the crucial message: `failed to open file:C:/dev/tty`. I guess in Linux it would be `/dev/tty` and the method would succeed. Here in Windows (this is in Windows, right?) something goes wrong with emulation(?) of `/dev/tty`. Somehow `ssh` tries to open `C:/dev/tty` which does not lead to the tty `sshpass` tries to set up. This is my hypothesis, I may be wrong. Unfortunately the only fix I know is "don't use Windows". There may be another fix, good luck. Consider [edit]ing and *explicitly* stating you're using Windows, if this is indeed the case.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski You're right! I'm attempting this using Cygwin in Windows. I've edited the title and tags as suggested. There must be a way though... Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@KamilMaciorowski comment lend me into the right direction. [According to this useful answer at ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/913435/110003), *Windows* is taking its own *OpenSSH* implementation. To solve this, `openssh` has to be installed in *Cygwin* in order to use this one instead.

This solves the errors and now I can do this:

```
$ gpg -d -q myappserver23.sshpasswd.gpg > pass_file && sshpass -fpass_file ssh myuser@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx > test.txt

$ cat test.txt
/home/myuser
uid=1001(myuser) gid=1001(mygroup) groups=1001(mygroup)
```

PD. This is not insecure because we're using `gpg` here. But if in doubt, [try this](https://serverfault.com/a/1033776/110003).

Answer (score 0):

Why decrypt to a plain text file which is just left in the filesystem?
Better to **pipe** the output directly:

```
gpg -d -q myappserver23.sshpasswd.gpg | sshpass -P pass ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem -ttR xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

The `-P pass` option searches for e.g a "password..." or "passphrase" prompt to fill.